# Binding Spring Form Tags to A Map

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a requirement to have my command object for the spring form tag binding to contain a Map to map a keyword to a "Y" or "N".

In the command object, the map is defined as such:

```
private Map<String, String> keywordResponseMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

In the JSP, I use radio buttons to generate the Y/N response:

```
    <c:forEach items="${form.eligibilityQuestions}" var="question">
        <c:set var="keyword" value="${question.keyword}" />
        <tr>
            <td width="75%">${question.text}</td>
            <td><form:radiobutton path="keywordResponseMap['${keyword}']" value="Y"/></td>
            <td><form:radiobutton path="keywordResponseMap['${keyword}']" value="N"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

The radio button control is NOT binding the Y or N into the map on form submit.

The Chrome dev tools show me that the submitted request parameter looks like this (yes, the space is intentional, the joys of fixed width data):

```
keywordResponseMap['RECORD4 ']:Y
```

Can anyone help?

Jason

Comment: What does your form handler method look like? What mechanism you use to determine the binding failed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a postprocessing method in the backing controller:

```
public void postprocessQuestions(RequestContext requestContext) {

    log.debug("Entered postprocessQuestions()");

    TrainingForm form = (TrainingForm) requestContext.getFlowScope().get("trainingForm");

    // manually get the reservation responses from the external request
    // context parameters
    Map<String, Object> requestParamMap = requestContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().asMap();
    for (String key: requestParamMap.keySet()) {
        if (key.startsWith("keywordResponseMap")) {
            String keyword = StringUtils.substringBefore("['", "']");
            String value = (String) requestParamMap.get(keyword);
            form.getKeywordResponseMap().put(keyword, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Then I had to turn off the automatic validation on the transition in order to run the postprocessign method before validation:

```
    <view-state id="renoExtendedEligibility" view="renoExtendedEligibility" model="renegotiationForm">
        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="flowController.enterQuestions(flowRequestContext)" /> 
        </on-render>
        <transition on="prev" to="QuestionsTransition" validate="false" />
        <transition on="*" to="QuestionsTransition" validate="false">
            <evaluate expression="renoFlowController.postprocessQuestions(flowRequestContext)" />
            <evaluate expression="renegotiationFormValidator.validateQuestions(renegotiationForm, validationContext)" />
        </transition>
    </view-state>
```

Thanks for the help!

Jason